# Facebook API integration error through php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I learned recently through some trial and error that requests to the Facebook graph API using the JavaScript SDK can sometimes return with the following error

```
    {
       "error":{
"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
"type":"OAuthException","code":2500
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick, but somewhat dirty solution is to add your access_token to each request as a parameter and not rely on the JavaScript SDK to do it for you:

```
//request to get profile information for the current user
FB.api("me", {
access_token: "<access-token-for-user>"
}, function(response){
//handle response here
});
```

More details

Typically, you would start your client side application by calling FB.init with the access_token for the user as a parameter. This is meant to ensure that any FB.api request made will be authenticated by attaching your access_token to the GET request to the Facebook graph. However, in some cases, your token may suddenly disappear from the application session and all requests to the graph will fail due to the token not existing on the GET request to the Facebook graph.

One reproducible scenario is to send an FB.api request to comment on a facebook post that has been deleted. Doing so will return an OAuth Exception error and erroneously delete the token from your current session.

```
By adding the token manually to all of your FB.api requests, you can ensure the token is always included.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code, access token is send in url here :

```
<?php

$facebook_appid         = "facebook_appid";                                 // Facebook appplication id
$facebook_secret        = "facebook_secret";                // Facebook secret id
$facebook_pageid        = "facebook_pageid";                                // Facebook secret id
$redirect_uri           = "https://localhost/facebook_page/events.php";   // return url to our application after facebook login ## should be SAME as in facebook application
//$redirect_uri         = "https://localhost/facebook_page/fb_login.php";   // return url to our application after facebook login ## should be SAME as in facebook application
$scope                  = "user_photos,email,user_birthday,user_online_presence,offline_access,manage_pages,publish_stream,user_events,friends_events"; // User permission for facebook


$code                   = $_REQUEST["code"]?$_REQUEST["code"]:"";

if(empty($code)) {
    $_SESSION['state']  = time(); // CSRF protection
    $dialog_url         = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=". $facebook_appid . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_uri) . "&state=". $_SESSION['state'] . "&scope=".$scope;
    header("location:".$dialog_url);
}

if($_SESSION['state'] && ($_SESSION['state'] == $_REQUEST['state'])) {
    $token_url          = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?". "client_id=" . $facebook_appid . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_uri). "&client_secret=" . $facebook_secret . "&code=" . $code;
    $response           = @file_get_contents($token_url);

    $params             = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);

    $account_url        = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$facebook_pageid."?fields=access_token&access_token=".$params['access_token'];
    $resp               = @file_get_contents($account_url);

    $dt                 =   json_decode($resp);


    echo $dt->access_token;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $dt->id;

    $offer_url        = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$dt->id."/feed?access_token=".$dt->access_token;
    $off                = @file_get_contents($offer_url);
    $dto                = json_decode($off);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($dto);


}

?>
```